# PayPal Get Access Token vb.net The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: vb.net, ssl, paypal-sandbox

I have a few questions on calling Grant Access Token API of PayPal, below is my code:

```
Public Function testAPI() As String
    Dim data As StringBuilder
    Dim byteData() As Byte
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim postStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim Result As String = ""
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Headers.Add("Username", "XXXXXXXXXX")
    request.Headers.Add("Password", "XXXXXXXXXX")
    data = New StringBuilder("{""grant_type"":""client_credentials""}")
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
    byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString())
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    If Not postStream Is Nothing Then postStream.Close()
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Result = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString
    Return Result
End Function
```

1. Am I passing Username and Password in right way?
2. Am I passing "grant_type":"client_credentials" in right way?
3. I keep getting error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. I have tried to add some code that I searched from google:

   ```
   ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
   request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11
   ```

But it still failed and return same error message. Please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the PayPal API, but just to try it, what happens if you do: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`? Also I assume you are setting these values _before_ calling `WebRequest.Create()`?

Comment: If it still doesn't work you might want to try posting this at their issue tracker as well: https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update/issues/

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you! I didn't put these code before the WebRequest.Create. But now I got another error that is 401 Unauthorized, so I believe my Username and Password or the grant_type didn't pass correctly.

Comment: I wonder if you were able to make this work. I have to convert to base64 the credentials to make the unauthorize error go away but  now my POST request was returning Bad Request (400) at GetResponse() and my guess is the data "grant_type=client_credentials".  Any update on this?